# Do I have to lose to win?

Tags: magikarp-jump

This is the progression so far in the last league that has frustrated me to no end:

1. Level up Magikarp to max before entering any league matches.  Takes about a day with the time period between training point refills
2. Progress through the league until a certain point is hit where the JP of my Magikarp does not exceed the other trainer's Magikarp, and thus I lose the match, ending in an early retirement
3. Retire the Magikarp, and go through all the cutscenes before catching yet another Magikarp
4. Repeat the process again.

I have done this loop for 3 times so far already in the Quick League, and with 3 more leagues left until the final league, it's frustrating me completely.   Is this the normal gameplay loop? Is there a way to retire my Magikarp early so that I can catch a new Magikarp with my new Trainer level so I can progress through without having to go through hitting that point where I have no choice but to restart? I would not like to play if this is the intended gameplay loop as, I feel like, wastes the whole point of catching "special" Magikarp that have benefits and whatnot, like the gold Magikarp.

Comment: Yes, the game works a bit like pokemon go, in that the main goal is levelling up your trainer so you can catch more powerful karp. Levelling things up to maximum both gives you a big chunk of xp and increases that motivation bonus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to retire your Magikarp early.  Though not as early as you're probably after.

If you click your trainer profile (the button showing your level and progress to the next trainer level), then scroll to the bottom, it has an item to retire the fish.  But it's only active after you have trained a certain number of times.

[image]

I'm not sure whether you get the large number of points bonus for doing so the way you do for completing training entirely though.

Comment: In your gameplay loop though, since the question wasn't really answered, did you have to lose repeatedly to end up eventually win that league?  Considering it took me 3 loops to get past the Quick League, and am now in the Heavy League, I would prefer to just stop playing if the loops is another 5-10 retirements just to complete one league.

Comment: @deadinside I believe the intent is that you level the fish up as high as it can go, it works through the league, and then you do it again - it's an incremental game, that's how they normally work.  Once have a sufficiently high trainer level, you will be able to beat the league - I have maxed out my stats.

Comment: @Margaret I know that you do still get an exp boost from the professor if you retire early. One strategy that I do is that when I am really close to a new trainer level but I know I won't get it until retirement, I'll go ahead and early retire so I can get the experience to get a trainer level.

Comment: @DustinKnight I don't understand the reasoning behind intentionally retiring your Magikarp early... you get additional trainer points every time you win a battle, so to maximise your gains, wouldn't it make sense to win as many as you can? That way you get the TP for the wins *and* for retirement.

Comment: @MageXy If you can early retire your magikarp you get a nice exp boost and its faster than battling. However, you would miss out on random events and coins. If you are really getting bored of doing the whole looping process though this can be a change of pace because you can get pretty good trainer experience which can in turn increase your magikarp level and allow you to go farther. Theoretically I would say that if you can retire fast enough you could probably get more exp per minute than you do while battling.